# Declared javascript function not binding correctly

Tags: jquery

I have the follow code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $(function detinator() {
                    $("select#arhpcnDetinator").jCombo("services/detinatori.php", { 
                            initial_text: "Detinator",
                            selected_value: $("input#arhpcndetinatorID").val()
                    });
});    
});
```

and everything is working perfect.

When I try to call same function on other event, it's stop working.

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $(function detinator() {
                    $("select#arhpcnDetinator").jCombo("services/det.php", { 
                            initial_text: "Detinator",
                            selected_value: $("input#arhpcndetinatorID").val()
                    });
    $("#imag").click(detinator);
    });
});
```

HTML is:

```
<img src="Sync.png" id="imag" onclick="ziceva">
```

Please help me! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove it from the double-wrapper you have there, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var detinator = function() {
      $("select#arhpcnDetinator").jCombo("services/det.php", { 
        initial_text: "Detinator",
        selected_value: $("input#arhpcndetinatorID").val()
      });
    };

    $("#imag").click(detinator);
});
```

Comment: The "double wrap" was weird.  I would move the function declaration out of the ready function.

Comment: This is not equivalent to his code unless you add a call to `detinator`.  It's a very odd construct which will result in that function being called on ready.  Though I doubt it's intentionally, his way would also add an additional `click` handler on each call.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to try something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

   $("#imag").click(function() {
                $("select#arhpcnDetinator").jCombo("services/det.php", { 
                        initial_text: "Detinator",
                        selected_value: $("input#arhpcndetinatorID").val()
                });

   });


});
```

Comment: this is not what I want, because when DOM are loading, jCombo feed my select box. After I add a new record (on the other window) I must refresh/reload select list and recall jCombo(jSON).

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the detinator function into javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    function detinator() {
            $("select#arhpcnDetinator").jCombo("services/det.php", { 
                initial_text: "Detinator",
                selected_value: $("input#arhpcndetinatorID").val()
            });
    }
    $("#imag").click(detinator());
});
```

Comment: You should not be calling `detinator`.  You are passing to `click` the return value of `detinator` which is nothing.  Also, the original code executes the function on `ready`.

Comment: But I must to call `detinator` function :). When DOM are loading, jCombo feed my select list. After I add a new record (on the other window) I must refresh/reload select list and recall jCombo(jSON) with a click on `#imag`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the open parenthesis `{` that you have after `$("select#arhpcnDetinator").jCombo("services/det.php",` is the problem. Remove it and try again..

Comment: That's not a parenthesis, it's a curly brace or bracket.  And I see no issue with it.